# jEdit - Filter SVN directories/files out of "Search in Directory" function

Tags: svn, jedit

Using the [jEdit](http://jedit.org/) programmer's text editor, given a directory of existing code, I have been searching for and updating references in directories using the "Search in Directory" function.  However, the directory also contains SVN files and subdirectories in addition to the code.

Is there an easy way to filter out these files when searching through the code directories with jEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I wasn't using the correct filtering syntax.  I needed to filter out the files explicitly for some reason.  More information about the filtering syntax is available at http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/globs.html .

Answer (score 0):

The .svn directories are hidden directories, aren't they? So just checking "Skip hiddens/backups" in that dialog should be enough. Or are there other hidden files or backups you don't want to skip?

If so, it could be a bit complicated. The "Filter" is only applied to the filenames, not to the folders. If you can make a filter that matches the files outside the .svn folders or the files inside the .svn folders it would be possible.

Comment: I checked "Skip hiddens/backups" and "Skip binary files", but I still run into issues.